# Erro No overload for matches delegate em um botão C#

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos

Estou programando um botao que confere se o login é existente e avança para uma outra tela porem aparece o seguinte erro:

> "no overload for 'btnEntrar_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'"

```cs
private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, String login, String senha)
{
    Cadastrar cad = new Cadastrar();
    cad.Acessar(txtLogin.Text, txtSenha.Text);
    if (cad.tem)
    {
        string nomeusu;
        MessageBox.Show("Logado com sucesso","Entrando",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        pnlCadMat.Visible = true;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nome_estudantes FROM Estudantes WHERE @login = email_estudantes AND @senha = senha_estudantes";
        nomeusuario = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        nomeusu = Convert.ToString(nomeusuario);

        cadh.lblNomeUsuario.Text = nomeusu;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("LOGIN NAO ENCONTRADO", "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O evento de click só pode ter 2 parâmetros. Um `object` que representa o elemento que disparou o evento e um `EventArgs` que são argumentos diversos para os eventos (por exemplo: um evento em um DataGridView pode conter a linha e coluna que disparou o evento).

Portanto, a assinatura do evento deveria ser

```
private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ter dois parametros no private void `btnEntrar_Click` que são os argumentos `(object sender, EventArgs e)`, você pode tentar passar seus parametros dentro de um text box invisivel por exemplo, colocar os valores lá e usa para sua função

```
    private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = SuaTextBoxLogin.text;
        string senha = SuaTextBoxSenha.senha;

        Cadastrar cad = new Cadastrar();
        cad.Acessar(login, senha);
        if (cad.tem)
    {
        string nomeusu;
        MessageBox.Show("Logado com 
        sucesso","Entrando",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        pnlCadMat.Visible = true;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nome_estudantes FROM Estudantes WHERE @login = 
        email_estudantes AND @senha = senha_estudantes";
        nomeusuario = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        nomeusu = Convert.ToString(nomeusuario);

        cadh.lblNomeUsuario.Text = nomeusu;
    }
    else{
        MessageBox.Show("LOGIN NAO ENCONTRADO", "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```